# NGINX Ingress giving 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable. nginx/1.19.1 error in frontend

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to install the Cyclos Mobile app on GCP Everything setup perfectly  but when I am trying to access the setup on browser it always showing either `default backend - 404` or `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable. nginx/1.19.1`. I have tried everything as per stack overflow several previous questions but still same error.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencypt-staging
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer":"letsencypt-staging","kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout":"3600"},"name":"cyclos-ingress-nginx-https","namespace":"cyclos-name-space"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"default-http-backend","servicePort":80},"rules":[{"host":"ip-address.xip.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"cyclos-app-stateful","servicePort":80},"path":"/*"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["ip-address.xip.io"],"secretName":"ip-address.xip.io-tls-secret"}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2020-09-29T07:00:01Z"
  generation: 11
  name: cyclos-ingress-nginx-https
  namespace: cyclos-name-space
  resourceVersion: "643221534"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/cyclos-name-space/ingresses/cyclos-ingress-nginx-https
  uid: uid
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: ip-address.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: cyclos-app-stateful
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ip-address.xip.io
    secretName: ip-address.xip.io-tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: IP
```

Comment: Could you post other `yaml` manifests? I mean `cyclos-app-stateful` `Service` and the `Deployment` it exposes ? If you provide us with fully reproducible example it will be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencypt-staging
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer":"letsencypt-staging","kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout":"3600"},"name":"cyclos-ingress-nginx-https","namespace":"cyclos-name-space"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"default-http-backend","servicePort":80},"rules":[{"host":"ip-address.xip.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"cyclos-app-stateful","servicePort":80},"path":"/*"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["ip-address.xip.io"],"secretName":"ip-address.xip.io-tls-secret"}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2020-09-29T07:00:01Z"
  generation: 11
  name: cyclos-ingress-nginx-https
  namespace: cyclos-name-space
  resourceVersion: "643221534"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/cyclos-name-space/ingresses/cyclos-ingress-nginx-https
  uid: uid
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: ip-address.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: cyclos-app-stateful
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ip-address.xip.io
    secretName: ip-address.xip.io-tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: IP
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.